# How to increase matched result when it is a number?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have this string:

```
var string = "this is test
               1. this is test
               2. this is test
               3. this is test
              this is test
               1. this test   
               2. this is test
              this is test";
```

Also I have this regex:

```
var match = /^[\s\S]*(?:^|\r?\n)\s*(\d+)(?![\s\S]*(\r?\n){2})/m.exec(string);
```

So `match[1]` is `2`. Now I need to increase that result. (I want `3`). How can I do that?

---

That regext matches `2`. In other word:

```
alert(match[1]); //=> 2
```

Now I need to increase that number. I mean is I want something like:

```
match[1]++; //=> I want: 3
```

How can I do that?

Comment: Maybe `Number(match[1]) + 1`?

Comment: @Tushar Look, the result of regex is a string, But I need to increase it as a number, is that possible?

Comment: also parseInt(match[1]) + 1